# How to reanimate terminal on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, terminal, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

When I type on my keyboard ctrl+alt+T or ctrl+alt+F1,2,3 and so on nothing happens.

I have raspbian Buster lite. And I've estblished raspberry to kiosk mode by adding chromium to  /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart

Where should I see to find something that doesn't allow to go to terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. In the file /boot/cmdline.txt was  `fbcon=map:2` when I removed it, everything became OK